# Вызов метода из другого класса

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

Есть 2 класса. Нужно в во 2 классе,выполнить метод из 1.
Сам метод:

```
    public void FLYNOTE_refresh(){
        SharedPreferences Pref = getSharedPreferences("nnote", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        key = Pref.getInt("number", 0); 
        String lv_arr[] = new String[key];
        for (int i = 0; i < key; i++){
    lv_arr[i] = Pref.getString("n" + i, "none");
    noten = i;
          }
          textView1.setText(String.valueOf(key));

    listView1.setAdapter(
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_arr));
    listView1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }

listView1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}
```

Как я его вызываю:

```
Client client = new Client();
client.FLYNOTE_refresh();
```

Приложение выкидывает ошибку.

Comment: один из классов точно является связанным с активити. А вызывающий класс тоже связан с активити? Если да, то Ваш код не может работать - так как пытаетесь обратиться до несуществующей в данный момент активити.

Comment: Так и думал.
Что тогда посоветуете? 
Не хочу тут таймер делать,для обновления данных.

Comment: ошибку покажи...

Comment: короче, видно что метод не будет рабочий вообще, так как у тебя у меня метод нечего не принимает и не возвращает, в нем ты пробуешь обновить текстВью в другом активити  - вот и ошибка

Comment: @Gorets откуда ты знаешь что второй класс о котором он говорит(Client) не находится внутри первого класса(Активити)

Comment: не было бы ошибки =)

Comment: оффтоп: почему многие придумывают какие то свои правила оформления java кода? это же не пайтон, за что вы так? :(

Comment: например? тебе нравится название его метода? мне нет..

Comment: @Gorets ну я как и не говорил, что мне нравится. По-моему в java принят camelCase и все со строчной буквы кроме классов. Мне просто читать даже неудобно, но это всё оффтоп оффтоп

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void FLYNOTE_refresh(Context c, TextView tv, ListView ...){
    // Тело фунцции
}
// Вызов функции
[Имя_класса(не экземпляра)].FLYNOTE_refresh(...);
```

Comment: не поможет ему

Comment: речи не было о 2х активити. Хотя из кода не очень понятно вобще о каких классах идёт речь. В определённой ситуации мой способ рабочий. В другой ситуации можно использовать хэндлеры.

Comment: Как раз-то 2 активности(

Comment: Верхняя активити прозрачная чтоли? зачем в ней обновлять нижнюю активити

Comment: Прозрачная активити? А определение можно?)) 
Это типа диалога? или активити с темой диалога?)) Короче, Рома, выложи 2е свои активити, скажи что ты хочешь и тебе скажут, что неправильно